# Unexpected results with MongooseJS findOne()

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

Using Mongoose as an ODM with NodeJS, but not fully understanding how the error handling works. It works, but doesn't look right, and isn't in line with the documentation, so I'm worried that going down this road will haunt me later on.

For example, here is a basic signin route:

```
app.post('/signin', function(req, res){
    var email = req.body.email;
    var password = req.body.password;
    mongoose.model('User').findOne({
        email: email,
        password: password
    }, function(err, user){
        if (err){
            console.log('Database Error')
            return res.json({error: 'Database Error'})
        } else {
            if (!user) {
                console.log('User not found.');
                return res.json({error: 'Email and/or password incorrect.'})
            } else {
                console.log('User ' + user.email + ' found. Logging in.');
                res.json({
                token: jwt.sign({}, 'top-secret', {subject: user}),
                data: data[user] 
                })
            }
        }
    })
})
```

I'm especially worried about:

```
if (err) {
    //do something
} else {
    if (!user){
        //do something else
    } else {
        //log the user in
    }
}
```

Haven't really used Mongo before today, but this feels like a lot of conditional error handling. Is there something that I'm not understanding properly here?

Comment: That looks just fine to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was going to post as a comment but it was easier to paste this as an answer..

You can simplify the if-else nesting since you are returning at the end of each conditional, like so:

```
app.post('/signin', function (req, res) {

    var email = req.body.email;
    var password = req.body.password;

    mongoose.model('User').findOne({
        email: email,
        password: password
    }, function (err, user) {

        if (err) {
            console.log('Database Error');
            return res.json({error: 'Database Error'});
        }
        if (!user) {
            console.log('User not found.');
            return res.json({error: 'Email and/or password incorrect.'});
        }
        console.log('User ' + user.email + ' found. Logging in.');
        res.json({
            token: jwt.sign({}, 'top-secret', {subject: user}),
            data: data[user] 
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks yeah. That simplifies it a bit. I guess I got thrown off by the mongoose docs, which didn't seem to have that conditional layer. http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-findOne